# ejs load template from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I just found this library called ejs, and I want to use it. According to the examples in the documentation I am doing the following:

```
var Ejs = require('ejs')

var loadTemplate = function () {
  var users = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'];
  var html = Ejs.render('<%= users.join(" | "); %>', {users: users});
};
```

Which is working fine, but what I want to do is to load the template from a file.. something like this:

```
var template = Ejs.render('url:/template.ejs', {users: users});
```

I am not being able to find any example of this simple case, any idea of how I can do this? without having to use fs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [tests](https://github.com/tj/ejs/blob/master/test/ejs.js), it looks like the renderFile function is what you want. I'm surprised it's not in the  documentation!

```
  var ejs = require('ejs')

  it('should accept locals', function(done){
    var options = { name: 'tj', open: '{', close: '}' };
    ejs.renderFile('test/fixtures/user.ejs', options, function(err, html){
      if (err) return done(err);
      html.should.equal('<h1>tj</h1>');
      done();
    });
  })
```